# ZF2 - Access DB Adapter in Controller

Tags: controller, zend-framework2, adapter, validation

Using Zend Framework 2, I am trying to add a DBRecordExists validator to a form in a controller. However, I continuously get exceptions that say "No database adapter present". I tried the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254574/how-to-get-zend-db-adapter-instance-from-within-a-model-zf2), but it did not appear to work. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

*AuthController.php*

```
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAwareInterface;

class AuthController extends AbstractActionController implements AdapterAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter
     */
    protected $adapter;

    /**
     * Input email address to retrieve a lost password.
     */
    public function lostpasswordAction()
    {
        // Create form
        $form = new UserForm();

        // Perform validation
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $user = new User();
            $form->setInputFilter($user->getInputFilter());
            $form->setData($request->getPost());
            $recordValidator = new RecordExists(
                array(
                    'table' => 'users',
                    'field' => 'email'
            ));
            $form->getInputFilter()->get('email')->getValidatorChain()->addValidator($recordValidator);

            //code    
        }
    }

    public function setDbAdapter(Adapter $adapter)
    {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
    }
}
```

*local.config.php*

```
<?php
return array(
    'di' => array(
        'instance' => array(
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => array(
                'parameters' => array(
                    'driver' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo',
                ),
            ),
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo' => array(
                'parameters' => array(
                    'connection' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection',
                ),
            ),
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection' => array(
                'parameters' => array(
                    'connectionInfo' => array(
                        'dsn'            => "mysql:dbname=owp;host=localhost",
                        'username'       => 'redacted',
                        'password'       => 'redacted',
                        'driver_options' => array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

*module.config.php*

```
<?php
return array(
    //other config code

    'di' => array(
            'Graduate\Controller\AuthController' => array(
                'parameters' => array(
                    'adapter'  => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter',
                ),
            ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this line to get current DB adapter in controller:

```
 $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
```

or

Refer this link,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17942232/2190889

With the help of this link you can set the DB Adapter in a Application/Module.php and you can use anywhere in your system.

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your RecordExists validator needs access to the DB Adapter.

Controller:

```
$recordValidator = new RecordExists(array(
    'table' => 'users',
    'field' => 'email'
));
// Need to pass to the validator..
$recordValidator->setAdapter($this->adapter);
```

Obviously it would be better to instantiate your RecrodExists validator using DI, and automatically inject the DB Adapter

DI Config:

```
'Zend\Validator\Db\RecordExists' => array(
     'parameters' => array(
          'adapter'  => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter',
      ),
 ),
```

Comment: I tried the both of these solutions. The first solution said that $this->adapter was null. The second solution does change the situation, but this time it throws another exception: "array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given", called in AbstractDb on 125, which is called by Di in 401.